# Dynamically added input fields with javascript, what are these fields' param names?

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I'm using the following example I found on the internet to dynamically build a list of input fields.

It seems to work fine, but when I submit the form, param names do I use to put the data from the HttpServletRequest?

Thanks, Rob

```
<HTML> 

<HEAD>     
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>     

<SCRIPT language="javascript">         

function addRow(tableID) {               
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);               
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;             
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);               
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);             
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");             
    element1.type = "checkbox";             
    cell1.appendChild(element1);               
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);             
    cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;               
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);             
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");             
    element2.type = "text";             
    cell3.appendChild(element2);           
}           

function deleteRow(tableID) {             
    try {             
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);             
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;               
        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {                 
            var row = table.rows[i];                 
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];                 
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {                     
                table.deleteRow(i);                     
                rowCount--;                     
                i--;                 
            }               
        }             
        }catch(e) {                 
            alert(e);             
        }         
    }       
</SCRIPT> 
</HEAD> 

<BODY>

<form name="myform" action="myServlet" method="post">

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />       
    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />       
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">         
    <TR>             
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>             
        <TD> 1 </TD>             
        <TD> 
            <INPUT type="text" /> 
        </TD>         
    </TR>     
    </TABLE>   

     <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>

</form>

</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your input objects a "name" attribute (or 'id' if your JSP isn't using name, but name is preferred I believe)

Try this:

```
function addRow(tableID) {               
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);               
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;             
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);               
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);             
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");             
    element1.type = "checkbox";             
    element1.name = "chk_input";      //*** EDIT ***            
    cell1.appendChild(element1);               
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);             
    cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;               
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);             
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");             
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "text_input";     //*** EDIT ***
    cell3.appendChild(element2);           
}
```

Then your params will be named "text_input" and "chk_input". You can replace this with something more meaningful of course.

I haven't used JSP in a while (I assume that's what HttpServletRequest is about...) so I can't remember how to access them, but those will be the keys.

EDIT: If you're dynamically adding rows, I suppose you need a unique name. It seems you are keeping track of the row count, so you could just do something like:

```
 ...
 element2.name = 'text-input-' + rowCount;
 ...
```

then in your controller (whatever processes the form) you could use the rowCount to set up a loop (for i .. rowcount) where you check for keys like "text-input-" + CastToString(i) for each row in the form.

If you're not passing rowCount with the form, just add an input of type hidden with a name='rowCount' and a value of the rowCount var. You can do this when the user clicks the submit button so you don't have to update it with each row)

```
form = document.getElementById('myform');
rc = document.createElement('input');
rc.type = 'hidden'
rc.value = rowCount; // make sure it's in scope!!!
form.appendChild(rc);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can click my "add" button many times.  Will each input require a unique name?  How would you suggest I handle this?

Comment: @Robert Hume See edit :) I realized that right after I first answered

Comment: Also i should add I made up CastToString -- I just wanted to point out that you have to cast it if it's not a string -- haven't used Java in a while

Comment: Very good.  One more question, using your code -- if I add rows (1,2,3), then delete the middle row (1,3), then add another row (1,3,3) I'll get a duplicate, right?  Is there a way around this, should I use a random six digit number or something instead of the row count?

Comment: Yeah, generating a random number (or using some form of timestamp) is probably the way to go. Then I guess you just iterate over all the keys... but if row number isn't in there then you won't know to which row this belongs... maybe something like "text-{rownumber}-{random}" and "chk-{rownumber}-{random}"

Comment: One more comment -- you can maintain a row count and a rowId variable. The count reflects the number of elements, whereas the rowId continually goes up, and is not affected when the number of rows is reduced. This way every row gets its own unique id, and rowCount is preserved if you need that variable in your controller.  Then you have "chk-1", "chk-3", "chk-4" if you add three rows, delete row two and add another row. Does that seem sensible?

I did something similar once: http://datasearch.limnology.wisc.edu/

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I think what I'll do is use "text"+random_six_digit number, then in the servlet I'll iterate through all param names that start width "text" to find them.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, what I did was have a "global" variable rowID that I increment on each "addRow" -- that way all the ids "text-1,text-2,text-5,text-6" are in the correct order even when items are deleted.  Thanks again for all the help!